# Xcode7: unknown type name error in a basic C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode7

I am working on a C++ program about STL with the latest version of Xcode, and I get the error "Unknown type name 'ubResultData'" and "Unknown type name 'ubFirstArgument'". I have tried to rewrite the program with standard unary_function and binary_function, and the errors remained the same. Then, I build the progaram with VS2010 and VS2013, and it built successfully. What's wrong with the program?

The errors are in the last line of class binder2ND.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename InputIterator, typename Predicator>
inline int countIF(InputIterator First, InputIterator Last, Predicator Pred){
    int count = 0;
    for (; First != Last; ++First) {
        if(Pred(*First))++count;
    }

    return count;
}

template<typename Arg1, typename Result>
struct UnaryBase{
    typedef Arg1 ubFirstArgument;
    typedef Result ubResultData;
};

template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Result>
struct BinaryBase{
    typedef Arg1 bbFirstArgument;
    typedef Arg2 bbSecondArgument;
    typedef Result bbResultData;
};

template<typename T>
struct LESS:public BinaryBase<T, T, bool>{
    bool operator()(const T& Left, const T& Right)const{
        return (Left < Right);
    }
};

template<typename BinOP>
class binder2ND:public UnaryBase<typename BinOP::bbFirstArgument, typename BinOP::bbResultData>{
protected:
    BinOP OP;
    typename BinOP::bbSecondArgument Arg2;
public:
    binder2ND(const BinOP& Oper, const typename BinOP::bbSecondArgument& valRight):OP(Oper),Arg2(valRight){}
    ubResultData operator()(const ubFirstArgument &ubArg1)const{return OP(ubArg1,Arg2);}
};

template<typename BinOP, typename rightVal>
binder2ND<BinOP> bind2ND(const BinOP& OP, const rightVal& vRight){
    return binder2ND<BinOP>(OP, vRight);
}

int main(){
    vector<int> myVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        myVec.push_back(rand()%100);
    }

    int countNUm = countIF(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), bind2ND(LESS<int>(), 30));
    cout << "Numbers=" << countNUm << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that errors and warnings when you have templates can be long-winded, but please include them all, verbatim and in full and unedited.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. These are exactly the errors I got, and I just copy them down. And the location is in the last line of class binder2ND.

Comment: Fyi, [gcc promotes the same error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82ddccaf5d9cebd6) as clang (your xcode toolchain, in case you weren't aware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the exact phrasing from the standard, but here's the simplified code that demonstrates the same behavior as yours:

```
template <typename T> struct A {
  typedef T X;
};

template <typename T> struct B: public A<T> {
  X x(void) { return 5; }
};
```

And here's the version that compiles without any errors:

```
template <typename T> struct A {
  typedef T X;
};

template <typename T> struct B: public A<T> {
  typename A<T>::X x(void) { return 5; }
};
```

So basically, you need to specify exactly where this type comes from.

It looks like VS* compilers are a bit more permissive than gcc or clang. :)